# How to solve route in Laravel 5 not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, laravel-5

I'm new php developer and interest use laravel framework5

when I access link `localhost/project/public/`

It's work

and i add function in route

```
> Route::get('home', function () {
>     return View::make('home.home'); });
> 
> Route::get('contact', function () {
>     return View::make('contact.contact'); });
```

i access link localhost/project/public/home or localhost/project/public/contact

it's show error 404 page not found

but i can access by localhost/project/public/index.php/home  but it's no have js file and css file

in my htacess file

> Options -MultiViews
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
>
> # Handle Front Controller...
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] </IfModule>
> ```

i use xampp  and enable mod_rewrite already

what wrong i missing to settings ?

Thank you

Comment: Try creating a virtual host pointing to that <project directory>/public. I am not sure why you have "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]" at the end. You can remove that. Once you create a virtual host add your domain name for example: "my_domain.dev" to your hostnames (/etc/hosts for linux). when you then access my_domain.dev it should render everything correctly with the css files provided they are in the public folder. Also I assume the home.blade.php exists in resources/views/home/ and contact.blade.php in resources/views/contact/.

Comment: This issue is mostly caused by `mod-write` but since you have enabled it, you should restart your `xampp`  if not done so

Comment: Why not serve the project using 'php artisan serve', that way it is guaranteed to work, without any problems.

Comment: For me to improve my answer, you could improve this question by showing your Virtual Host config.  My answer may not necessarily fix the problem because I'm not sure your host config is pointing to the correct place.

Comment: I just move `root/public/.htaccess to root/.htaccess` and it works

Answer (score 2):

Try to see your routes with the following command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

And see what you get.

Execute this after:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

try again.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your Virtual Host is not configured correctly.  Since I cann't see exactly how this is done my assumption is your Virtual host is not setting **public** as Document root:

Try something like the following.

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/YOURHOST/public>
    AllowOverride None
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

*Notes*

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] < /IfModule>

So essentially this will never run because of the previous RewriteRule is being executed and stopped due to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Clear the previous cached routes once and then try

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use the command

```
php artisan serve
```

in your project root where the artisan file available
and then you can access your project by using 
http://localhost:8000